# web page loading time

Tags: javascript

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var myWin = window.open("http://www.hizlial.com/hediyelik/hediyelik-urunler/zippo-jack-daniels-ltr-flask-hediye-seti_16.004.4126.1233.htm","_blank")
window.onload = function() { opener.window.endtime = new Date().getTime(); }
var endTime = opener.window.endtime;
var timeTaken = endTime-startTime;
document.write(timeTaken);
```

i edited the new code but this time i couldnt write the timeTaken value? so whats wrong here?

Comment: the window.onload line should be in the target code, in this case http://www.hizlial.com/hediyelik/hediyelik-urunler/zippo-jack-daniels-ltr-flask-hediye-seti_16.004.4126.1233.htm , then you should also call a finish callback from the opened window. So your opened window should have window.onload = function() { window.opener.endTime = new Date().getTime(); window.opener.finished();};

Comment: can you fix the code pls? and write here if u can.. im not so good in js.. i need timeTaken value on the screen

Answer (score 1):

That's because javascript isn't a threaded language, meaning that it doesn't wait for things to happen, it will open the page and while the page is loading will go on and do other stuff. What you would need to do is to add this into the target page:

```
window.onload = function() { window.opener.endtime = new Date().getTime(); }
```

Or as ramazan murat wrote:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime(); var myWin = window.open("www.mozilla.com");
window.onload = function() { opener.window.endtime = new Date().getTime(); };
var timeTaken = endTime-startTime;
```

Another way to go about this would be to do this:

```
<script>start = new Date().getTime();</script>
<iframe src="http://www.mozilla.com/" onload="end=new Date().getTime();"></iframe>
```

Comment: var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var myWin = window.open("http://www.hizlial.com/hediyelik/hediyelik-urunler/zippo-jack-daniels-ltr-flask-hediye-seti_16.004.4126.1233.htm","_blank")
    window.onload = function() { opener.window.endtime = new Date().getTime(); }
    var timeTaken = endTime-startTime;

Comment: i edited my question and updated my code as you said.. but it isnt working. i made a mistake? dou have any idea? it didnt write timeTaken value to screen this time

Answer (score 0):

I would use Net in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to test a page's load time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Chrome's developer tool's [timeline function](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhaWYQ44WEc).

Comment: what exactly do you mean? how will i use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do this programmatically, then Firebug's [Net tab](http://getfirebug.com/network) will give you all the information you need to know about how long given resources on a page take to request.